# .NET Framework 4.5 error in Xamarin Starter Edition on Windows 10

Tags: .net, xamarin

I am currently doing some assignments for a class and I could not run any set of code at all without this error appearing:

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(5,5): Warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. (MSB3644) (Comments_Console)"

So I found this stack overflow page and tried doing the both of the answers: [Xamarin Error: Framework not installed: .NETPortable, Version=v4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066108/xamarin-error-framework-not-installed-netportable-version-v4-5)

I downloaded the Portable Tools 2 extension, and tried running it in the command prompt as "PortableLibraryTools.exe /buildmachine" which failed to run on my end. I also ran the command prompt in administrator mode with the same result.

I also notice that in my reference assemblies folder, there is no .NETPortable folder at all, and all of the existing SDKs are installed into the Framework folder, with no folders that go beyond that.

I'm only using Xamarin for C# for my class for now, so that's all I'll be using.

I don't really know how to fix my error. I already tried running the regular .NET Framework 4.6 but it's not Compatible for Windows 10.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change to the ALPHA channel as they have put a fix in place to fix that issue. I had the same issue and that resolved it for me.