# Asp.net 5 Publish not working? but project build and runs Expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dnx

**can anyone have work around for below issue !!!..**

**Overview of my Situation**

1. I have worked in xamarin project like android ,ios apps.  i was
   choose portable lib to communicate database and azure services,
   xamarin project are works expected with portable lib.
2. Now iam working on wep project using asp.net 5 and angular js , i was       completed all features and functionality using existing portable libiary ,its build  runs expectd.
3. **but** when publish the web project . i was get the error below

   `Error NU1002: The dependency Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10 in project xxxxxxxx.Core does not support framework .NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78`.

   `Error NU1002: The dependency Microsoft.Bcl.Async 1.0.168 in project xxxxxxxx.Core does not support framework .NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78`.

   `Error NU1002: The dependency Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29 in project xxxxxxxx.Core does not support framework .NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78`

   `Error NU1002: The dependency Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.1 in project xxxxxxxx.Core does not support framework .NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78`

   `Error NU1002: The dependency WindowsAzure.MobileServices 1.3.2 in project xxxxxxxx.Core does not support framework .NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78`

   `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error : Build failed`.

Here are my logs [publish](http://pastebin.com/b2BfTuAc),[build](http://pastebin.com/4du9R2KV) ,[project.lock.json](https://gist.github.com/jaganjan/d0ae153bd2b29f26baf0)

**MY Web project configuration**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls=http://localhost:5000"
  },


  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "xxxxxx.Core": "1.0.0"
      }
    },
     "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "xxxxxx.Core": "1.0.0"
      }
    }
  },

    "exclude": [
      "wwwroot",
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "publishExclude": [
      "**.user",
      "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "scripts": {
      "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
    }
  }
```

**xxxxx.Core** Is a poratble class lib , here is a portable class refrence configuarion

[image: portable lib targeted framworks]

***did i made any mistake in configuration***? , i dont know how to resolve the issue anyone help me out to this issue.Thanks

**Update** Issue is Resolved FROM .NET CLI and changes will be out from [DNX RC2](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2967#issuecomment-196911594)

***Edits Welcome***.**

Comment: why is marked down ?please post your comment i will update the question

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066108/xamarin-error-framework-not-installed-netportable-version-v4-5) post?

Comment: thats only for seems to installation issue,now iam getting this  issue publish only,this issue is already  marked bug from ASP TEAM,So I need workaround.do u understand

Comment: the error is telling you that an assembly(s) are not supported in .net 4.5 have you tried changing the properties of the project to build using .net 4.0 framework..?

Comment: @MethodMan i cont downgrade the project beacause i was working prototype..i was debug and run the project with out any issues,but i con't publish

Comment: dont know why you received so many down votes for this question??? I've just ran into this problem now. Its really annoying me

Comment: @Phil The Asp team accept is defect and also this will  fixed in RC2, check the updates in above link . maybe i was asked silly question ? i think so..

Comment: @phil the present workaround remove other platform dependencies.its works only windows platform

Answer (score -1):

Since the error is `...does not support framework .NETPortable,Version=v4.5` as an informal test I would try to change the target .Net version, for example, as @MethodMan said, with .Net 4.0

Answer (score -2):

When prepare release make sure your IDE is in release mode. Make sure each project are in the same version. Make sure same version is installed in your production server. If it shows problem, please reset your IIS.

Comment: iam publish to filesystem

Comment: project  also release only